# Pyspark not able to read csv file with special character(ø) as delimiter

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

My csv files looks like this:

```
idøageøname
1ø25øAshutosh
2ø21øShipra
3ø11øNimisha
4ø15øBhavya
5ø7øSammridha
```

I am not able to read this csv file(delimiter is ø). Pyspark command below is reading complete line as one column instead of 3.

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("sep", "ø").csv('file_path.csv')
```

Comment: What encoding does the csv file use? Have you tried using UTF-8 or your local characterset?

Comment: I am specifying any encoding for csv file. Do I need to, if yes then how?

Comment: What encoding does the file you use for test use?

Comment: try ```....option("encoding", "UTF-8").....´´´

Comment: @tifi90 UTF-8 should be the default

Comment: @NineBerry, I know. Just wanted to answer how to change the encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created the same csv on my machine and could read the data with "ISO-8859-1".

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1").option("sep", "ø").csv('file_path.csv')
```

For more information on the encoding just check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 and the code page layout